# MySQL syntax error in Ruby on Rails scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, spree, multi-tenant

I'm working in a RoR application using Spreecommerce, but my application is not a simple ecommerce is a plataform with many tenants, and each tenant have a single store. So, it's a single application with many stores. I'm using rails 4.2.2 and spree 3-0-stable branch.

To create my tenancy structure i'm based in this gem:
[spree_multi_tenant](https://github.com/stefansenk/spree_multi_tenant)

And using this gem too: [acts_as_tenant](https://github.com/henriquenm/acts_as_tenant)

My code:

```
module SpreeMultiTenant
  def self.tenanted_models
    [
      Spree::Address,
      Spree::User,
      Spree::Promotion,
      Spree::PromotionRule,
      Spree::PromotionAction,
      Spree::PromotionActionLineItem,
      ...
    ]
  end

  def self.tenanted_controllers
    [
      Spree::BaseController,
      Spree::Api::BaseController,
      ...
    ]
  end

  def self.with_tenant(tenant, &block)
    ActsAsTenant.with_tenant tenant do
      SpreeMultiTenant.init_preferences
      yield
    end
  end

end
```

To controllers:

```
class Spree::Preferences::StoreInstance
    def set_without_persist(key, value)
      @cache.write(key, value)
    end
  end

  module SpreeMultiTenant
    def self.init_preferences
      Spree::Preference.all.each do |preference|
        Spree::Preferences::Store.instance.set_without_persist(preference.key, preference.value)
      end
    end
  end


  SpreeMultiTenant.tenanted_controllers.each do |controller|
    controller.class_eval do

      set_current_tenant_through_filter
      prepend_around_filter :tenant_scope

      private

        def tenant_scope
          tenant = Spree::Tenant.find_by_domain(request.host)
          if tenant
            set_current_tenant(tenant)

            SpreeMultiTenant.with_tenant tenant do
              yield
            end
          end
        end

        def set_current_tenant_through_filter
          self.class_eval do
            helper_method :current_tenant

            private
              def set_current_tenant(current_tenant_object)
                ActsAsTenant.current_tenant = current_tenant_object
              end

              def current_tenant
                ActsAsTenant.current_tenant
              end
          end
        end
    end
  end
```

To Models:

```
SpreeMultiTenant.tenanted_models.each do |model|
  model.class_eval do

    belongs_to :tenant
    acts_as_tenant :tenant
  end
end
```

All others areas of the store it's working properly, but when the customer click to buy a product, i've got this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (spree_promotions.starts_at IS NULL OR spree_promotions.starts_at < '2016-02' at line 1: SELECT * FROM ( SELECT `spree_promotions`.* FROM `spree_promotions` INNER JOIN `spree_orders_promotions` ON `spree_promotions`.`id` = `spree_orders_promotions`.`promotion_id` WHERE `spree_promotions`.`tenant_id` = 1 AND `spree_orders_promotions`.`order_id` = 2 AND (spree_promotions.starts_at IS NULL OR spree_promotions.starts_at < '2016-02-19 19:22:01.592902') AND (spree_promotions.expires_at IS NULL OR spree_promotions.expires_at > '2016-02-19 19:22:01.593065') UNION SELECT `spree_promotions`.* FROM `spree_promotions` WHERE `spree_promotions`.`tenant_id` = AND (spree_promotions.starts_at IS NULL OR spree_promotions.starts_at < '2016-02-19 19:22:01.593151') AND (spree_promotions.expires_at IS NULL OR spree_promotions.expires_at > '2016-02-19 19:22:01.593601') AND `spree_promotions`.`code` IS NULL AND `spree_promotions`.`path` IS NULL ) `spree_promotions`
```

Yes, the error is here: **WHERE `spree_promotions`.`tenant_id` = AND (spree_promotions.starts_at**

But why my tenant_id is empty? Why my scope is not working in this case?

I saw others spree_promotions mysql queries and it's normal:

```
SELECT  `spree_promotions`.* FROM `spree_promotions` WHERE `spree_promotions`.`tenant_id` = 1 AND `spree_promotions`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

So i have no ideia to fix it :(